# CONCAT() result containing CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Database setup:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d1c2/1

Following query selects all tags which belongs to productID and their places, comma separated:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', GROUP_CONCAT(Tags.Name)) 
FROM `ProductTags` 
LEFT JOIN Tags ON ProductTags.TagID = Tags.TagID
WHERE `ProductID` = 46356
GROUP BY DisplayOrder
```

It can contain 1-3 rows.

More complex query shows category, full of (like 50-100) products.
I want all tags be available at once, pass them to juery and then display.

**The question is**: how can i concat() this query into one field, so i only have one big query, or should i handle it with php and have like 100 queries at page?

Comment: Consider providing some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty don't know if this helps, but only question here is "how concat() results of concat()". i need this resulting table to use it in other query, so i want it like "tag,tag,tag,tag;tag,tag;tag,tag"

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d1c2/1

Comment: for sample data see link above, expected result - all three rows in resulting set in one string.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I get you right, but this could be one solution:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Tags.Name)) 
FROM `ProductTags` 
LEFT JOIN Tags ON ProductTags.TagID = Tags.TagID
```

This will show you all Tags for all productTags. (**DISTINCT** makes the names unique)

Comment: This query will result in pretty much similar results as mine, containing 3 rows. And i need to **use this query results as field** in other query, containing all products.

Comment: and when you don´t use Group By? then all are in one row

Comment: how can i see which tag belongs to which displayOrder?

Comment: this is only possible with GROUP BY.......... 
`SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Tags.Name)) AS Tag, DisplayOrder
FROM ProductTags
LEFT JOIN Tags ON ProductTags.TagID = Tags.TagID
GROUP BY DisplayOrder`
.....but then you can´t have them in one row